# Reactjs, strange behavior on checking state value (again)

Tags: reactjs

Ok, there is something I don't understand again:

```
  onDateChange(child, performUpdate){
    console.log("child", child, child.state);
  }
```

As you can see, from the debugeur, the state has some value. But when I try to access them, they act like if they where not initialized. Like if the setState wasn't an atomic operation after all...

Actually I don't have any idea as it seems counter intuitive.
Can someone help me to get my data from the callback. Every operation in js/reactjs act differently from what it is expected.
Is that because the 'state' property is in another field and duplicated? I can't find any logical reason for this strange behavior.

[image]

**edit**:

So it appear that setState is asynchronuous. And worst part, non atomic operation. This is kind of strange they don't speak of that in the documentation (instead they said to not use state directly but by method call. Why? Because they do the change in another thread without telling the client!!!).

So this is how you have concurrency problem like I had. 
Is there a clean approach for this kind of problem? Like a callback on setState method when all the operation are done (some people use delay or inline function, which absolutly don't correct the problem ).

To resolve my issue, I had to use a proxy pattern where there is the datastructure independantly from the view who display it, and act as if it was the same object. So that the controller don't have to deal with all this 'background' threaded operation mess. (Note: the datastructure is not a model, but a readonly object).

Comment: Where do you call the check?

Comment: In the parent. From what I understand for the behavior, the operation is not atomic. Thanks to React not informing it in the doc. Why... I just found an article about my belief. This is a so big antipattern /medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

Comment: If you look closely at the documentation of `setState` function, you will find the second parameter is a callback. In fact they encourage you to use `setState` with a callback, like this: `setState((prevState) => { console.log(somevar);})`. If you want to manage very complex states you better use `redux` or `mobX`.